# Call a Fragment from an Activity (from OnClickListener)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a button inside my Activity and when I click on this button I want to call a Fragment.

For example if I want to call an Activity I can use the intent but if I want to call a Fragment, how can I do that?

I have checked other questions but I have not found an answer to what I'm asking.

```
btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

What am I going to put inside this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your fragment dynamically.You want to create a fragment.

To programmatically add or remove a Fragment, you will need the **FragmentManager** and **FragmentTransaction**

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/myFrame" <!-- Id which you're gonna use in Java -->
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();

   MyFragment myfragment = new MyFragment();  //your fragment 

 // work here to add, remove, etc
  fragmentTransaction.add (R.id.myFrame, myfragment);
  fragmentTransaction.commit ();

    }
});
```

[See this doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: On R.id.myFrame what i'm going to put ?

Comment: You've to create a frame layout or any other layout with id inside your activity layout and then use that id in java

Comment: See this @marte http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-fragments-to-an-activity-in-android/

Comment: @marte Now see my updated answer. Hope this will help you to understand better

Comment: i totally understand thank you so much for your time. Very helpful. !!   :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open new fragments. Fragments need to be always hosted by an activity. If the fragment is in the same activity (eg tabs) then the back key navigation is going to be tricky I am assuming that you want to open a new screen with that fragment.
So you would simply create a new activity and put the new fragment in there. That activity would then react to the intent either explicitly via the activity class or implicitly via intent filters.

The answer to your problem is easy: replace the current Fragment with the new Fragment and push transaction onto the backstack. This preserves back button behaviour...

Creating a new Activity really defeats the whole purpose to use fragments anyway...very counter productive.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment newFragment = new chartsFragment(); 
    // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit(); 
}
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions

***Quotation***