# Call a specific Button from navigationViiew

Tags: java, android, navigationview

I have a bottom navigation view in my activity_main.xml file in my app. Until Now, When I wanted to set it from my MainActivity.java i did:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigationV);
```

And everything worked fine. Now, In this navigation view there are 2 buttons, And I want to set them seperately. Is that possible in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Code like this

```
   bottomNavigationView .OnNavigationItemSelectedListener . 
   mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_shop:
                toolbar.setTitle("Shop");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_gifts:
                toolbar.setTitle("My Gifts");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_cart:
                toolbar.setTitle("Cart");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: What if we press the buttonB in the NavigationView, it will display the FragmentB. Do you know how to make it?

Comment: yes it's possible , check this answer where fragment is placed in activity on click of button . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817614/call-a-fragment-from-an-activity-from-onclicklistener

Comment: Thanks. I just wondered if there is a way to set each Button separately.